# Multi-value parameters in ssrs

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a multi-value parameter. how I get one by one values from this parameter.

value=new_index and label=new_french

and want to insert these values into these labels

Answer (score 0):

You can access the individually selected multi-value parameters by their index (the index is zero-based). So if you want the first selected parameter value (for example, to put it into a label), you can address it like so:

```
=Parameters!MyParameter.Value(0)
```

You could access them all using custom code:

```
Function DoSomething (ByVal parameter As Parameter) AS String
  Dim Result As String
  If parameter.IsMultiValue then
    For i As integer = 0 To parameter.Count-1 
      Result = Result + CStr(parameter.Value(i)) + ", " 
    Next 
    Result = Left(Result, Result.Length - 2)
  Else 
    Result = CStr(parameter.Value)
  End If 

  Return Result
End Function
```

then use this expression to access the result:

```
=Code.DoSomething(Parameters!MyParameter)
```

Note that you are passing the parameter object here, not the `Value` property. We access the Value property in the custom code function.